# get an argument list with sublists

Tags: r, nested-lists

I would like to flatten this list of arguments

```
args <- list(
  a = 1,
  b = "2",
  list = list(c = 3, d = list(d1 = 5, d2 = 6)),
  e = data.frame(e1 = c("a", "b"), e2 = c(7, 8))
)
```

on this

```
args <- list(
  a = 1,
  b = "2",
  c = 3, 
  d = list(d1 = 5, d2 = 6),
  e = data.frame(e1 = c("a", "b"), e2 = c(7, 8))
)
```

Because I need get work this function call

```
g <- function(x, y, ...){
  do.call(f, x, y, ...)
}

g(x = x1, y = y1, args)
```

That does not work:

```
reduce(
  .x = args,
  .f = function(x) {
    ifelse(
      is.list(x),
      lapply(x, `[[`),
      x
    )
  }
)
```

that throws

```
Error in fn(out, elt, ...) : unused argument (elt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of map always be the same dim. So you need a for loop.

> ```
> output <- NULL
> for (x in seq(length(args))) {
>    list <- args[x]
>   if (is.list(args[[x]]) && !is.data.frame(args[[x]])) {
>     list <- flatten(args[x])
>   }
>   output <- append(output, list)
> }
> ```

```
output
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] "2"

$c
[1] 3

$d
$d$d1
[1] 5

$d$d2
[1] 6


$e
  e1 e2
1  a  7
2  b  8
```

Comment: this solutios preserves the names

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** to OPs new data:

```
purrr::c(flatten(args[1:3]), args[4])

$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] "2"

$c
[1] 3

$d
$d$d1
[1] 5

$d$d2
[1] 6


$e
  e1 e2
1  a  7
2  b  8
```

As you already state in your question "I would like to flatten this list of arguments" -> We could use `purrr`s `flatten()` function:

```
library(purrr)

flatten(args)
```

```
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] "2"

$c
[1] 3

$d
$d$d1
[1] 5

$d$d2
[1] 6


$e
[1] 5
```

Comment: Maybe specify `purrr::flatten`?

Comment: I added a data.frame in the elements, that I need to stay equal. Maybe with `map_if`? But that one returns the same leght as the input

Comment: Please see my update. This could be one way!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below using `for` loops

```
res <- c()
for (v in args) {
    if (is.list(v) & !is.data.frame(v)) {
        res <- c(res,v)
    } else {
        res <- c(res, list(v))
    }
}
```

or via `Reduce`

```
res <- Reduce(
    function(x,y) {
        c(x, ifelse(is.list(y) & !is.data.frame(y), I, list)(y))
    },
    args,
    c()
)
```

and you will obtain

```
> res
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] "2"

$c
[1] 3

$d
$d$d1
[1] 5

$d$d2
[1] 6


[[5]]
  e1 e2
1  a  7
2  b  8
```

Comment: interesting anwers, rounding my thinkings about.

`fun <- function(i, x){
  if(is.list(i) & !is.data.frame(i)){
    list(x, flatten(i))
  } else {
    list(x, i)
  }
}
args2 <- reduce(
  .x = args,
  .f = fun
)`
But i do not understand my fail